# Need to calculate height of remaining div using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a second div filling the area not taken up by the header, and no footer. The second div's height is not defined except by height: calc(100% - 155px);. All good it works,
but it's not working for Safari 5.1.7 on pc (and there's no more Safari updates for pc, so I need a fix for pc Safari users). How can I do the same thing using jQuery?

```
   html, body, #wrapper { height: 100%; }

    CSS  
    #headerHome {height:146px;}
      #center {
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: -moz-calc(100% - 155px);  
    height: -webkit-calc(100% - 155px);     
    height: calc(100% - 155px); 
  }
  .sliderBox{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
  }

    HTML    
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="headerHome">
            HEADER STUFF 
        </div>
        <div class="redBorder"></div>
        <div id="center">                
            <div class="sliderBox">
               SLIDER STUFF HERE                    
            </div>                
           <div class="centralWrap">
        MAIN CONTENT HERE           
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the jquery version of your code here it is:

```
  //heigh of your window - height of your header or just set 155
  var height = $(window).height() - $('#headerHome').outerHeight();
  $('#center').height(height);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LQPJh/)

Comment: Thanks for that h0mayan. It does give me what I want as far as the height for #center goes, but the slider stuff doesn't like it as much as the height: calc(100% - 155px); approach. The sliders loose their responsiveness too which isn't good.